# FontSize.PIXELS c# equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, j#

I have following J# code

```
bigFont = new Font("Arial", bigFontSize, FontSize.PIXELS);
```

How I can convert above line to c# [`FontSize.PIXELS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa250533%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: If its J# then the C# should be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", bigFontSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141986.aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the GraphicsUnit.Pixel on the contstructor:

```
Font f = new Font("Arial", 25, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
this.Font = f;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [this constructor for the Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), taking a font-family, an emSize, and a graphics unit.

In that case, you want a [GraphicsUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumeration.

And it looks like the specific equivalent you want is `System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel`.